# Send Google file to email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have built a sidebar in Google App Scripts and on some action I would like to send a document to email and would like it to appear in email like when you share a document you get a kind of widget of the document with the file title some text a button etc.

Is it possible to attach a file like this and not as a PDF?

[image: something like this]

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean that if you send an email the user recieving it can see basic information about the document and have a button to go to/open the document?

Comment: @Chris yes, the user has access to the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [easily attach](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage) a [Google Document or any Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source) to an email as well as construct an email with information about the document including a link, using the following code:

```
var myDocument = DocumentApp.openById(<DOC_ID>);
var mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(<SPREADSHEET_ID>);
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "recipient@example.com",
    subject: "My Email",
    htmlBody: "Document Name: " + myDocument.getName() + ". " +
              "Document Link: " + myDocument.getURL(),
    attachments: //Or just attach the Docs... If you don't want to, remove this option
      [
        myDocument,
        mySpreadsheet 
      ]
  });
```

**Edit:** The `htmlBody` does, obviously, use HTML can be styled as you would a webpage. My example is very basic. **There is no standard card or widget offered by Google.** They offer the HTML implementation is to be extremely flexible so that we can create our own! There are many free email templates out there, I have used Litmus's free templates in the past.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I know that I can send email with html, probably was not clear in my question. Is there some standard widget (card) which I can use to send the information about the document with?

Comment: @Tornike. There is no standard card or widget offered by Google. I think the reason they offer the HTML implementation is to be extremely flexible so that we can create our own! There are many free email templates out there! I have used [Litmus's free tempaltes](https://litmus.com/community/templates) in the past.